# How to use Correct Conditioning?

Tags: android

**Is this the correct query?**

```
DbFertility info = new DbFertility(this);
        info.open();
        String name = info.getUserInfo();
        info.close();

        if(name != null){
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Create.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }else{
            Intent i2 = new Intent(this, CalendarMain.class);
            startActivity(i2);
        }
```

problem: if the name null i want to direct it create class.. my real problem is even my name is empty or not it always direct me to the CalendarMain.(help)

```
 public String getUserInfo() { 
      String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_USER_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_AGE, KEY_STATUS}; 
      Cursor c = getOurDatabase().query(TABLE_USER, columns, null, null, null, null, null); 
      String result = ""; 
      int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_USER_ID); 
      int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME); 
      int iAge c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AGE);
      int iStatus = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_STATUS); 
      for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) { 
           result = result + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iAge) + c.getString(iStatus) + "\n"; 
      }
      return result;
}
```

Save:

```
  public long createUser(String name, String age, String status) {           
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(); 
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, name); 
        cv.put(KEY_AGE, age); 
        cv.put(KEY_STATUS, status); 
        return getOurDatabase().insert(TABLE_USER, null, cv);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `TextUtils.isEmpty(name)`, it returns true if the string is null or if its length is equal to zero.

```
Intent i = null;
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
     i = new Intent(this, Create.class);     
} else {
     i = new Intent(this, CalendarMain.class);
}

startActivity(i);
```

Comment: still it direct to calendarMain, i dont get it my database is empty

Comment: are you sure you are getting the information from the database?

Comment: yes by using the String name = info.getUserInfo(). correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: well that depends on what you saved on the database. If the database is empty, it will no return nothing. Maybe you can post how do you save/read the data from the database?

Comment: This is how i save it:            String name = sqlName.getText().toString();
   String age = sqlAge.getText().toString();

   int select = rgStatus.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
   RadioButton statusbutton = (RadioButton) findViewById(select);
   String status = statusbutton.getText().toString();

   DbFertility entry = new DbFertility(Main.this);
   entry.open();
   entry.createUser(name, age, status);
   entry.close();

Comment: This is how i save it:  String name = sqlName.getText().toString();
   DbFertility entry = new DbFertility(this);
   entry.open();
   entry.createUser(name, age, status);
   entry.close();  public long createUser(String name, String age, String status) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
  cv.put(KEY_NAME, name );
  cv.put(KEY_AGE, age);
  cv.put(KEY_STATUS, status);
  return getOurDatabase().insert(TABLE_USER, null, cv);

Comment: This is How i read it: public String getUserInfo() {
/ TODO Auto-generated method stub String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_USER_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_AGE, KEY_STATUS}; Cursor c = getOurDatabase().query(TABLE_USER, columns, null, null, null, null, null); String result = ""; int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_USER_ID); int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME); int iAge c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AGE);int iStatus = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_STATUS);  for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){ result = result +  c.getString(iName) + " " +  c.getString(iAge) + c.getString(iStatus) + "\n"; }return result;}

Comment: is `getOurDatabase` returning an instance of `DbFertility` ?

Comment: what do you mean by instance? 
public SQLiteDatabase getOurDatabase() {
  return ourDatabase;
 } if u mean this... yes